# Android oboe - How to change rate / frequency of a AudioStream after it has been opened

Tags: android, oboe

When working with Android SoundPool you can alter the playback rate with the following API and adjusting the rate:

```
SoundPool play(int soundID, float leftVolume, float rightVolume, int priority, int loop, float rate)
```

My question is how to do so within the Android oboe library. I know you can set the frequency to a AudioStreamBuilder, but once the stream has been opened, can you then change the rate on the fly?

Comment: For whoever downgraded the question, please add some detail explaining why you did so, so everyone can learn and benefit.

Comment: It certainly wasn't me, this is a great question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resampling is not supported in Oboe. It might be added in future, however, it's more likely to be added in a supporting library or in a sample.

If you want to implement this you could use libresample from FFmpeg ([here's how to add FFmpeg to Oboe](https://medium.com/@donturner/using-ffmpeg-for-faster-audio-decoding-967894e94e71)).